# Where can I learn more about pilots' dreams during G-LOC?

Tags: military, pilots, medical, fighter, g-forces

I came across an extremely interesting note from a [wiki article on G-LOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-LOC) (g-force loss of consciousness, or blackout):

> Brief but vivid dreams have been reported to follow G-LOC.

Sadly no citation. Where can I read more about this? I did a quick Google search on "pilots dream g-force blackout" but only got 2 relevant hits that didn't tell me much. Some reddit posts described a dream trapped in a maze and a trip to Hawaii, that's about it. They sometimes described it as an out-of-body experience instead of a dream.

Does anyone know where to go to read more? Is this really a common phenomenon?

Comment: This was mentioned in the TV episode JetStream - a program about Canadian fighter pilot training, around 20 minutes into episode 1. You may look it up online.

Comment: The topic seems pretty "on" to me - a question about an unusual experience that is apparently had by pilots while flying; not only that, but interesting too.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if you've come across this or not, but the paper [Recovery from 
Gz-lnduced Loss of Consciousness:Psychophysiologic Considerations](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a200214.pdf) has some details on this phenomenon. It describes the tests carried out on eight volunteers.

- This does not appear to be very common- five 'dreams' were recalled out of 21 acceleration runs. The subjects seem to have indicated that these were definitely 'dreams' as opposed to 'thoughts'. Also, the report notes:

> ... it is difficult objectively to determine exactly what the subjects experienced during their individual G-LOC episodes (dream or thought) or even state that G-LOC can be equated to a normal sleep mental state (in relation to dream activity)

Another paper [Further Support for the  Concept of a  G-LOC Syndrome: A Survey of Military High-Performance Aviators](https://dokumente.unibw.de/pub/bscw.cgi/d5424523/ASEM_2000_71%285%29_496-500.pdf) shows that the dream-like state occurs in about 15% of the cases.

The 'dream' state appears to be restricted to <13s and vary from person to person (in some cases, they were not aware that they've lost conciousness).